# Use TransformDataset without using AnalyzeAndTransformDataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-transform

I am trying to use tensorflow transform and I would like to serialise a whole pipeline composed by different transformations. Let say I have a transformation that doesn't have to be fitted (as feature interaction between numeric columns). I want to use the `TransformDataset` function directly on the preprocessing function I have already defined. Anyway it seems this is not possible

If a run something like this

```
import pprint
import tempfile

import apache_beam as beam
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_transform.beam as tft_beam
from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import dataset_metadata, schema_utils

NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS = ['a', 'b', 'c']
impute_dictionary = dict(b=1.0, c=0.0)

RAW_DATA_FEATURE_SPEC = dict([(name, tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32)) for name in NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS])
RAW_DATA_METADATA = dataset_metadata.DatasetMetadata(schema_utils.schema_from_feature_spec(RAW_DATA_FEATURE_SPEC))


def interaction_fn(inputs):
    outputs = inputs.copy()
    new_numeric_feature_keys = []

    for i in range(len(NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS)):
        for j in range(i, len(NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS)):
            if i == j:
                outputs[f'{NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS[i]}_squared'] = outputs[NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS[i]] * outputs[NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS[i]]
                new_numeric_feature_keys.append(f'{NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS[i]}_squared')
            else:
                outputs[f'{NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS[i]}_{NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS[j]}'] = outputs[NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS[i]] * outputs[ NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS[j]]
                new_numeric_feature_keys.append(f'{NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS[i]}_{NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS[j]}')

    NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS.extend(new_numeric_feature_keys)

    return outputs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    temp = tempfile.gettempdir()

    data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        a=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
        b=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0],
        c=[0.9, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    ))

    data.to_parquet('data_no_nans.parquet')

    x = {}
    for col in data.columns:
        x[col] = tf.constant(data[col], dtype=tf.float32, name=col)

    with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
        with tft_beam.Context(temp_dir=tempfile.mkdtemp()):
            raw_data = pipeline | 'ReadTrainData' >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet('data_no_nans.parquet')
            raw_dataset = (raw_data, RAW_DATA_METADATA)
            transformed_data, _ = (raw_data, interaction_fn) | tft_beam.TransformDataset()

            transformed_data | beam.Map(pprint.pprint)
```

I get the error

```
2020-02-11 15:49:37.025525: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-02-11 15:49:37.132944: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f87ddda6d30 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-02-11 15:49:37.132959: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
WARNING:tensorflow:Tensorflow version (2.1.0) found. Note that Tensorflow Transform support for TF 2.0 is currently in beta, and features such as tf.function may not work as intended. 
WARNING:tensorflow:Tensorflow version (2.1.0) found. Note that Tensorflow Transform support for TF 2.0 is currently in beta, and features such as tf.function may not work as intended. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrea.marchini/Hackathon/tfx_test/foo.py", line 56, in <module>
    transformed_data, _ = (raw_data, interaction_fn) | tft_beam.TransformDataset()
  File "/Users/andrea.marchini/.local/share/virtualenvs/tfx_test-jg7eSsGQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 482, in __ror__
    pvalueish, pvalues = self._extract_input_pvalues(left)
  File "/Users/andrea.marchini/.local/share/virtualenvs/tfx_test-jg7eSsGQ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_transform/beam/impl.py", line 908, in _extract_input_pvalues
    dataset_and_transform_fn)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable PCollection object
```

Is the `TransformDataset`supposed to be used only on the result of the `AnalyzeAndTransformDataset` one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could you try this:

```py
transformed_data = (raw_dataset, interaction_fn) | tft_beam.TransformDataset()
```

I think it tried to unpack `raw_data` which does not contain the metadata. Moreover `TransformDataset` returns only on variable, not two.